# Automator: Safari: Display Webpages, but no entry area?

Tags: macos, automator, automation

I'd like to have Safari automatically open up a webpage when an action is run, but with this action, it appears there is no area where I can enter the particular webpage that I want Safari to display (e.g. macrumors.com, ...).

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need something to give the action an input. The Display Webpages action doesn't request for user input by default, since it could use the value of a variable, etc as the URL.

Use an action such as **Ask For Text** before the Display Webpages action. Note that the Ask For Text action doesn't parse URLs, so you'll need the `http://`.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to just have it do this automatically with multiple URLs? (E.g. Open 5 URLs in new tabs in one Safari window, one after another)

Comment: @JFW Yeah, see the other answer.

Comment: Brilliant, just did that. Is it possible to have Automator (it is a long shot) to, after opening all these webpages, save each one as a .webarchive (+S, confirm)? Thanks.

Comment: Also is it possible to make Safari open a new window before starting this sequence of commands? (I've already found Launch Application --> Safari. Just need to do this.)

Comment: @JFW There's no built-in action to download URLs as webarchive, but you could script a ⌘S, ↩︎, ⌃⇥ (save, confirm, next tab, repeat).

Comment: Right. Thanks for the response. How can I script this? Is there a particular action where I can just add in these keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: @JFW Not exactly — it'd probably be worth a separate question…

Comment: Not exactly regarding 'opening new window', or scripting the '⌘S, ↩︎, ⌃⇥ (save, confirm, next tab, repeat)'?

Comment: You can use AppleScript (this can be in an Automator action) to accomplish keystrokes like command-S and enter. I'm not sure how you would open the URLs in a new window, though… Maybe AppleScript can do: tell application "Safari" to open "http://example.com" in a new window

Comment: Right. I think the latter part is fairly easy to solve. Just pull Safari into view (Action: Launch Application: Safari) and then use the keystroke +N to open a new window. Is the scripting for using keystrokes in AppleScript hard? I'm afraid I'm not a coder, nor am I familiar with AppleScript as a language itself.

Comment: @JFW See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690167/how-can-one-invoke-a-keyboard-shortcut-from-within-an-applescript

Answer (score 1):

The intended URLs can be passed into the action by the Get Specified URLs action, or one of the other Safari actions to get web addresses. Getting text works as well.

Comment: Brilliant, just did that. Is it possible to have Automator (it is a long shot) to, after opening all these webpages, save each one as a .webarchive (+S, confirm)? Thanks.

Comment: Also is it possible to make Safari open a new window before starting this sequence of commands? (I've already found Launch Application --> Safari. Just need to do this.)